# mysql sort on many to many relation condition

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
groups:
    id          : integer
    group_title : string

group_sessions:
    id          : integer
    group_id    : integer
    start_time  : timestamp
```

I need to sort groups based on latest upcoming session `start_time`. So for example group A has next session on tomorrow, and group B has next session today. Then group B should come first. This is what I wrote but obviously its not working

```
select g.id, g.group_title
from groups g
left join (
    select group_id, MIN(start_time) as min_session_time
    from group_sessions
    where start_time > now()
    group by group_id
) s on g.id = s.group_id
order by min_session_time asc
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need an INNER JOIN here, not LEFT JOIN.
Second, you don't need aggregates, like MIN.

```
SELECT g.id, g.group_title, gs.start_time
FROM groups g
    INNER JOIN group_sessions gs ON gs.group_id = g.id
WHERE gs.start_time > NOW()
ORDER BY gs.start_time
```

Comment: I am not getting any results with `WHERE gs.start_time > NOW()` this condition. where as i have active session. If i remove the condition, I get results but old ones.